# Copying image content to clipboard in vifm

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, vifm

I'm trying to write a command in vifm (on linux) that copies the content of an image to the clipboard, using copyq.

This is what I got so far:

I use the command `xdg-mime query filetype myfile.jpg` to get the mimetype.

I use `qcopy` to write the content of the file to the clipboard like this:
`qcopy write $MIMETYPE - < myfile.jpg`

The following command works fine in the shell and the content of the file gets copied to the clipboard:
`qcopy write $(xdg-mime query filetype myfile.jpg) - < myfile.jpg`

Now how can I rewrite this command as a vifm command in my `vifmrc` file?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
command! copyf
\| let $MIMETYPE = system(expand('xdg-mime query filetype %c'))
\| execute expand("copyq write $MIMETYPE - < %c && copyq select 0")
```

I just get an "Invalid command name" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues here:

1. By default command's body is executed by the shell, if you start it with a colon, it will be processed as an internal one.  See [help](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%3Acommand).
2. You need to have a space between command name and its body and writing `copyf\n<spaces>\|` results in first argument of `:command` being `copyf|`, hence `Incorrect command name` error. [Help](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-vifmrc).
3. `qcopy` was spelled as `copyq` in one place.
4. [`:execute`](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%3Aexecute) runs an internal command, internal command called `!` runs a shell command, so `!` needs to be used on the last line.
5. `%` in a body of a command is expanded automatically, need to double it to escape so that it's expanded later.  Last line is expanded also by `expand()`, so double escaping of `%` there.

Fixed version that should work:

```
command! copyf
    \ : let $MIMETYPE = system(expand('xdg-mime query filetype %%c'))
    \ | execute expand('!qcopy write $MIMETYPE - < %%%%c && copyq select 0')
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! I'm not sure it's the simplest way to write down that command but it does the job.